# How to distribute ruby on rails offline applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, distribution

I was following the solution on [this answer for distributing rails apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711/options-for-distribution-of-an-offline-ruby-on-rails-application/56333#56333) but it seems like it's not up to date for everything with slingshot.

I just can't get it working. Is there a new or another way to get a rails application distributed into offline exe file and .app for Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 1):

I went down this path a year or two ago and didn't find any success. I couldn't ever get Slingshot to work with 2.3.x Rails apps, I even thought about deploying the application on an entire OS system wrapped up into a virtual .exe using Xenocode (which is now Spoon Studio). Ultimately, I rebuilt the back-end Ruby stuff in javascript and deployed it as an AIR app, not something I'd recommend or even do again myself.

There's another thread on this topic with some other options listed in the answers and comments:

[Distributing Rails Applications as Native Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183121/distributing-rails-applications-as-native-application)

Good luck.